# Cumulative count with altair

Tags: python, data-visualization, altair

I'm trying to plot data with a date as the X axis and several cumulative counts as Ys.

I have a set of items such as:

```
id1 date1 user1
id2 date2 user1
id3 date3 user2
```

With this example, I'd want the plot to have 2 lines, the X axis would have three entries (date1, date2, date3) and user1 would have a Y-value of 1 at date1, 2 at date2, 2 at date3; user2 would have 0 at date1, 0 at date2, 1 at date3.

Directly making a Chart, I can't see what I should use to have this cumulative count. E.g.

```
Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x='date:T', y='count(*)', color='username')
```

obviously creates a chart where most values are 0 (few entries have exactly the same date).

Ideally,

```
Chart(data).mark_line().encode(x='date:T', y='cumcount(*)', color='username')
```

would work, but there doesn't seem to be an equivalent [in the documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/documentation/encoding.html).

In my real case, I have ~10 users and a few thousand entries over a few months.

Comment: While I have answered below to make the required plot via Pandas' manipulations, it may be worth to keep a tab on the issue: https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/348

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think cumulative count aggregation is yet available in Altair. In the meanwhile, one can do the corresponding manipulation in Pandas. Here is one such way. I am sure there can be more efficient ways of doing so.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
user_list = ['user1', 'user2']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':range(2000, 2010),
                  'username':np.random.choice(user_list, 10)})
```

This is how `df` looks like.

```
    date    username
0   2000    user1
1   2001    user2
2   2002    user2
3   2003    user1
4   2004    user2
5   2005    user2
6   2006    user2
7   2007    user2
8   2008    user2
9   2009    user2
```

Cross-tabulation

```
d = pd.crosstab(df.date, columns=df.username).cumsum()
d = d.stack().reset_index()
d = d.rename(columns={0:'CummulativeCount'})
```

This is the output of `d.head()`.

```
date    username    CummulativeCount
0   2000    user1   1
1   2000    user2   0
2   2001    user1   1
3   2001    user2   1
4   2002    user1   1
```

Now, we can use Altair without bothering about any aggregation.

```
from altair import Chart
c = Chart(d)
c.mark_line().encode(x='date:T', y='CummulativeCount:Q', color='username')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In this end, I did it like you suggested, although not as cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this directly in Altair [as in this example in the docs](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/cumulative_count_chart.html). Here is another example showing a cumulatitve count with a line chart (often called an empirical cumulative distribution function (ecdf) although technically I think the y-axis is often normalized for those [as in this example](https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/empirical_cumulative_distribution_function.html) using `cume_dist` instead):

```
import pandas as pd
import altair as alt


df = pd.DataFrame({'values': np.random.normal(size=100)})

alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='values',
    y='cumulative_count:Q',
).transform_window(
    cumulative_count='count()',
    sort=[{'field': 'values'}]
)
```

[image]